# Finding the mean and variance of a discrete variable.

Tags: probability, expected-value, variance

This is the question

Suppose that $X$ is a discrete random variable with the mean $4$ and variance $9$. If $Y= -2X+1$. What is the mean and variance of $Y$?

I was able to easily solve the mean $E[Y]$ like so:

$E[Y] = E[-2X+1] = -2E[X] + 1 = -2(4) + 1 = -8 + 1 = -7$

but I got a little confused about solving the variance. This was my attempt

$VAR[Y] = E[Y^2] - (E[Y])^2 = E[(-2X + 1)^2] - (-7)^2 = ?$

My issue is handling the $E[(-2X + 1)^2]$ portion well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $E[-2X+1]^2=4E[X^2]-2E[X]+1$, and remember that $\operatorname{Var}[X]=E[X^2]-(E[X])^2$.

Or you can use directly the fact that $\operatorname{Var}[aX+b]=a^2\operatorname{Var}[X]$.

Comment: Thank you, sir! I noticed that the E[X] term was avoided in some workings? Is this accurate. Kindly reference this link - https://www.quora.com/Suppose-that-X-is-a-discrete-random-variable-with-the-mean-4-and-variance-9-If-Y-2X-1-What-is-the-mean-and-variance-of-Y/answer/Marn-Rivelle-2?__filter__=all&__nsrc__=1&__sncid__=8147234961&__snid3__=12098328825

Comment: @IsaacAttuah : you are right! The linked solution is wrong. See my answer for details

Answer (score 0):

The enclosed link gives a wrong result

$$\mathbb{V}[-2X+1]=(-2)^2\mathbb{V}[X]=4\times 9=36$$

in the enclosed link the calculation of $\mathbb{E}[Y^2]$ is wrong. It's 85 and not 101.

I suggest you not to follow that brainstorming, boring and useless for your problem